# how to color print out the code in APSX/CS files of visual studio?

Tags: printing, visual-studio-2010, color-printer

As you know that when you edit the ASPX or CS file they are formatted in different colour to show different objects, but when I try to print out these source code or files, the output is black & white ... and just to let you know that the printer mode is set to color.

Comment: It seems this is something they took out from VS 2010. VS 2008 prints in colour OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print from Notepad++.

It's not as convenient as you have to open the file in a second editor, but it does syntax highlighting and prints in colour.